# Django Sum on distinct values

Tags: django, aggregate, distinct

I have three models:

ModelA, ModelB and ModelC

ModelB has a field called value, which I try to aggregate. However to find the correct ModelB instances I have to filter through fields of ModelC, which means I will have duplicates. Using the distinct clause on ModelB instances, means that I cannot use the Sum aggregate because that will raise a NotImplementedError from Django (Distinct + Aggregate is not NotImplemented).

Query:

```
ModelB.objects.filter(model_a=some_model_a, model_c__in=[some_vals]).distinct('id').aggregate(Sum('value'))
```

I could do something like this:

```
models_b = ModelB.objects.filter(model_a=some_model_a, model_c__in=[some_vals]).distinct('id')
sum = 0
for model_b in models_b:
   sum += model_b.value
```

This is obviously quite heavy and slow. Is there anyway to circumvent the issue of the NotImplementedError?

I already tried SubQueries, pg_utils with DistinctSum (almost what I need, but I need the distinction on id not on value) and some stuff with values.

Edit: I forgot to mention that ModelC has a ForeignKey to ModelB and ModelB has a ForeignKey to ModelA. Therefore 1 ModelA has N ModelBs, and 1 ModelB has N ModelAs.

Edit2: I forgot to mention that I have the whole thing mapped out as a SQL Query and it works. However, I need the flexibility from the DjangoORM. Otherwise I have my headaches at a different spot. There I used group by clauses instead of distinct values, but I do not know how to achieve this in DjangoORM.

Comment: Re. Edit2: did you confirm the working SQL query is faster than query + looping in Python? It's not obvious that looping is prohibitively heavy and slow. If looping could be acceptable, are your indexes set up for the accompanying query? You could also try using `.only()` to speed it up a little.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The pure SQL is about 250ms, the SQL + Python Loop is about 2.5 seconds.

Comment: The use of only() is new to me, I will check that one out. Thanks already for mentioning that.

Answer (score -1):

I think this should work,

```
models_b_id = ModelB.objects.filter(model_a=some_model_a, model_c__in=[some_vals]).distinct('id').values_list('id',flat=True)
stats = ModelB.objects.filter(id__in=model_b_id).aggregate(sum=Sum('values'))
```

queries are faster than loop.

Comment: This looks interesting, I never thought about using the values_list with flat=True here. I will test it and come back to you as I won't be able to test this until tomorrow.

Comment: Please test your code before answering "This should work" isn't acceptable and shouldn't be answered. I've personally tested this and this doesn't work (at least in the current version of Django anyway).